# Micro Integrator 4.2.0 maven build - error - Invalid CEN header

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mi

I am new to ws02, I am trying to build ws02 micro integrator from Ubuntu 22.04 terminal + Maven 3.6.3 + JDK 17.0.10+7. I am facing problems, getting error "Invalid CEN header" during the compilation. I explain all steps I did.

1. **Downloaded JAVA JDK 17.0.10+7**  OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.10_7.tar

   from https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/?os=linux&arch=x64&package=jdk&version=17
2. **Set JAVA HOME path in .bashrc**

   jammy@Tasconnect-016:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME

   /opt/jdk-17.0.10+7
3. **Verified Java version**

   jammy@Tasconnect-016:~$ java --version

   openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16

   OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7)

   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7, mixed mode, sharing)
4. **Verified maven version 3.6.3**

   jammy@Tasconnect-016:/$ mvn --version

   Apache Maven 3.6.3

   Maven home: /usr/share/maven

   Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /opt/jdk-11.0.18+10
5. **Cloned the repo from** https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator

   jammy@Tasconnect-016:~/mi$ git clone https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator.git
6. **List branches for mi 4.2.0** version

   ```
   jammy@Tasconnect-016:~/mi/micro-integrator$ git branch -r | grep "4.2.0"
     origin/master-4.2.0
     origin/release-4.2.0-alpha-l895
     origin/release-4.2.0-d731
     origin/release-4.2.0-m1-p301
   ```

   7 . **Checked out branch "origin/release-4.2.0-d731" -** assuming this is the release version branch for MI 4.2.0

   ```
   jammy@Tasconnect-016:~/mi/micro-integrator$ git checkout origin/release-4.2.0-d731
   ```

   8. Gave command , wanted to skip jacoco tests

```
 mvn clean package -Dskip.jacoco.check=true
```

9 . Got below error "  Invalid CEN header " at

[INFO] data-services ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.013 s]

[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Data Services Common ................. SUCCESS [  0.216 s]

[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Data Services SQL Driver ............. SUCCESS [ 30.548 s]

[INFO] WSO2 Carbon - Data Services Core ................... SUCCESS [01:18 min]

**[INFO] WSO2 Micro Integrator - Mediation Initializer ...... FAILURE [ 47.939 s]**

[INFO] extensions ......................................... SKIPPED

[INFO] WSO2 Micro Integrator - Transport Handlers ......... SKIPPED

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDxOS.jpg)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.3.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer: Error calculating classpath for project MavenProject: org.wso2.ei:org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer:4.2.0 @ /home/jammy/mi/micro-integrator/components/org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer/pom.xml: The JAR/ZIP file (/home/jammy/mi/micro-integrator/components/mediation/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.micro.integrator.inbound.endpoint/target/org.wso2.micro.integrator.inbound.endpoint-4.2.0.jar) seems corrupted, error: Invalid CEN header (invalid extra data field size for tag: 0xbfef at 242516) -> [Help 1]

So search for this *org.wso2.micro.integrator.inbound.endpoint-4.2.0.jar* file inside ~/.m2/repository . But found no such file .

But I found the file inside *~/mi/micro-integrator/components/mediation/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.micro.integrator.inbound.endpoint/target .*

Deleted it rm -f  *org.wso2.micro.integrator.inbound.endpoint-4.2.0.jar . Rebuild with "mvn package -Dskip.jacoco.check=true" again same error .*

Now again I went back to ~/.m2 folder and I searched for all files with string "inbound.endpoint". Found 3 entries with suffix *-4.7.175.jar" not exactly "4.2.0.jar"

grep: ./org/wso2/carbon/mediation/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence/4.7.175/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence-4.7.175.jar: binary file matches

grep: ./org/wso2/carbon/mediation/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.osgi/4.7.175/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.osgi-4.7.175.jar: binary file matches

grep: ./org/wso2/carbon/mediation/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint/4.7.175/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint-4.7.175.jar: binary file matches

Deleted these 3 files

Re-ran the command mvn package -Dskip.jacoco.check=true ( without clean because I did not want to rebuild all previously built JARs) . But again same error thrown "Invalid CEN .

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following is from the README of the source repo. Hence try downgrading to JDK 11.

> Please note that the product can be build using only JDK 11 but the
> integration tests can be run in either JDK 11 or 17.